# Passing multiple dataframes to a function that contains an if statement in R

Tags: r

I have a function below that contains an IF statement, the error message is:

> 1: In if (df == "iris1") { :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Can anyone amend the code so that it works?

```
library(tidyverse)
iris1<-iris[1:50, ]
iris2<-iris[51:100,]

add_col<-function(df,colname)
  {
    df$newcol<-df [, colname]*100
if(df=="iris1"){df<-df%>%mutate(col_id="some text")}    
if(df=="iris2"){df<-df%>%mutate(col_id="other text")}    
return(df) 
}

x <- c("iris1", "iris2")

z<-map(map(x, ~ as.symbol(.x) %>% eval),
    ~ add_col(.x, "Sepal.Length"))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to perform different actions based on the name of a variable passed to a function rather than the value itself? That seems very odd and would really restrict how you can use the function. Such a function wouldn't work with with `map` because `map` passes along values, not variable names. You should really reconsider how you are trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a named `list` and then use `imap` to loop over the `list`

```
library(purrr)
add_col<-function(df, nm, colname)
  {
    df$newcol<-df [, colname]*100
if(nm =="iris1"){df<-df%>% mutate(col_id="some text")}    
if(nm=="iris2"){df<-df%>%mutate(col_id="other text")}    
return(df) 
}
```

-testing

```
out <- imap(lst(iris1, iris2), ~ add_col(.x, .y, "Sepal.Length"))
> map(out, head, 2)
$iris1
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species newcol    col_id
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    510 some text
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    490 some text

$iris2
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species newcol     col_id
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor    700 other text
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor    640 other text
```